# parameter deliver issue among web pages

Tags: html, http

I found that when you capture parameter value delivered from other pages, the "+" sign in the parameter value will be replaced with space. I'm not sure if there is other signs to be replaced. So my question is, besides using string.replace() method, any other way to avoid such value changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use url encoding to encode protected characters in your URL.

See: [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for reserved characters and not reserved characters. Nearly every language has its URL encoding implementation.

For example the Character `+` is reserved and will be replaced by `%2B`

Another reference can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).